# Это приложение? Нужен ли знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение

> Тема картины «Семья».

«Семья» это приложение? Нужно ставить перед ним тире или двоеточие?

А здесь:

> Тема картины называется «Семья».

Answer (score 1):

Если это заглавие (в этом случае после "картины" имеется пауза), то я могу предложить такой вариант:

> Тема картины - "Семья"

Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными в именительном падеже при нулевой связке между ними.

---

Тема картины называется "Семья".
Тут почти то же самое, однако здесь видно полноценное составное именное сказуемое, состоящее из глагола "называется" с ослабленным лексическим значением и существительного "Семья".

---

Если взять отдельно:

> картина "Семья"

То в нем "Семья" будет приложением. Картина (какая) "Семья".

---

Со словом "тема" не могу составить подходящий по смыслу пример, привожу подобный:

> "История картины "Семья" была интересна каждому"

В данном случае "Семья" выступает в роли приложения.